# Can I make 3D plot in Python where Z is not a function of X,Y -- AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_data'

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, data-visualization, graphing

I am trying to understand how to use Python to make a 3D plot. I have three variables -- X,Y, and Z. Here, X simply denotes a date, Y is a second time dimension, and Z are values.

For a concrete example, suppose I have weather forecast data. At each date x a weatherman provides a weather forecast for the next 9 days. Thus, the second time dimension, Y, are days 1 through 9 of the forecast. Z holds the actual value of forecasts. I want to make a 3d plot that shows these forecasts values at each day. I could do this in a 2d graph where X is date, Y is forecasted values (what would be Z if done 3D) and then I have 9 lines showing the 9 forecasted value at each date.

Clearly, Z =\= f(X,Y) but there is a unique value z for each grid point in the X,Y plane. So, it seems like this should be possible. However, I am a complete amateur with making 3D graphs in Python.

Currently, my data look like this:

X'=[date1, date1, date1,...,date1,date2,....,date2...] where each date shows up 9 times.

Y'=[1,2,...9,1,...9,...]

Z'=[Day1Forecast1,day1forecast2,...day1forecast9,day2forecast1,...]

UPDATED EDIT ---

Here is an example of what I've tried:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filepathgoeshere')
print(df.head(5))

X = df['DATE']
Y = df['y']
Z = df['z']

X = df['DATE']
Y = df['j']
Z = df['H']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
Axes3D.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, color='black')
```

I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_data'"

Comment: It doesn't really matter if `Z` is related to `f(X,Y)` or not. As long as you can iterate through your data in the correct manner so that the appropriate `Z` value is paired with the corresponding `X,Y` values, you can plot them very easily. Check out the `matplotlib` package for one visualization option.

Comment: I tried using some approaches from matplotlib but continually received an error message regarding the fact that Z is not 2-dimensional.

Comment: Are you sure you were using the 3D plotting tools? To get help with your actual program, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and put it in your question. It'll be a lot easier to get you going on the right track if we have some code and sample data to work with.

Comment: Okay. Let me read through the link and i will do that. Thanks for your help and your patience so far.

Comment: Here's the [`mplot3d` tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) from the `matplotlib` docs - they're quite helpful.

Comment: @MattDMo -- i read through that and it looks like i ought to be able to use trisurf. Updated my code and now am receiving a  new error message. Is this specific enough yet for more pointed feedback?

Comment: Can you update with the full text of the traceback? I'm guessing there's an issue with reading your Excel file. Also, why do you assign to `X`, `Y`, and `Z` twice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying 2 years late, but for anyone else who lands on this thread, this works for me:
First I create a 3d graph and define the axis names:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
```

Then I create lists made up of the data:

```
t = [1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24] # t is time of the day
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # n is number of the day 
data1 = [day1forecast1, day1forecast2, ..., day1forecast9] 
data2 = [day2forecast1, day2forecast2, ..., day2forecast9]
data3 = [day3forecast1, day3forecast2, ..., day3forecast9]
...
data9=...
```

In this case, you create a list of data for each day. There needs to be as many values in each data-list as there are in the time list, because those values are going to be paired together later on. It is worth noting that 'n' and 't' do not need the same amount of values. Basically, the data-lists form a 2D matrix, 't' is going to be linked to each column and 'n' to each row.

This is a simple way of creating a 2D matrix. I've written more code than necessary to make it easier to understand what is going on:

```
rows, cols = (3, 9) 
data = [[0]*cols]*rows
data[0]=data1
data[1]=data2
data[2]=data3
```

If you want to project over 9 days, then input 9 for number of rows, i just didn't want to make 9 data lists.

Ive just added this so you can change which values go on which axis so as to get exactly what you want, it also allows you to make the link between the variables I have defined and those given in the example:

```
x=w
y=t
z=data
```

Then I create a mesh which connects all the points together, and the I plot the whole thing

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.contour3D(X, Y, z, 50, cmap='binary')
```

I hope this helps! :)